# Windows workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

Just want to learn 'Windows workflow' designer in .net right from the basics, can anyone suggest a good link please

thanks
sandeep

Comment: See **duplicate** question already asked: > [Windows workflow..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89353/windows-workflow)

Answer (score 1):

OdeToCode has several in depth articles on WWF written by Scott Allen, and in particular a good discussion of the instances where you should use [a state machine](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/460.aspx) to simply complex workflow logic.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735927(VS.85).aspx)  a link to some good beginner-level WF tutorials:

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the MSDN section yet?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735967.aspx

EDIT: heh—someone posted the link while I was writing.

Answer (score 0):

Except from the obvious MSDN link, you may find useful the following:

- [Screeencast: Your first sequential workflow](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/matt/archive/2008/09/23/screeencast-your-first-sequential-workflow.aspx) and
- [Screencast: Your first state machine workflow](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/matt/archive/2008/09/23/screencast-your-first-state-machine-workflow.aspx) by Matt Millner

Answer (score 0):

Hands-on Labs for Windows® Workflow Foundation in C# and VB.NET
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2e575633-e357-4ee7-aaff-34138f00e830&displaylang=en

Very good guide for your first steps.